# Create heat map that groups genes by expression within cluster in Seurat

Tags: seurat, single-cell, gene-expression, heatmap

I have a set of cells that I am performing Drop-seq on to look at cell expression.  Among my heat maps for gene expression I want to be able to graph them similar to the graph below:
[image: Heat map with clusters on left, genes on bottom, and genes grouped together]

Where the cells are sorted by cluster on the left axis, and have the genes across the bottom.  However I also want to cluster the genes by the expression within the cluster (like how this graph does).  Is that possible in Seurat?

Currently I have created a heat map that looks like this:
[image]

It has the clusters listed on the left axis, and small sub-selection of genes on the bottom.  However I want to be able to order those genes by their expression within those clusters, without having to manually order the genes when I insert them into the "feature" argument.

Here is a sample of the code I am currently using to plot the graph:

(Note: I have an object "Combined" that has the non-averaged cell expression, but for now I do want to use average expression)

```
png("ExpressionHeatmap%03d.png", res=600, width=14, height=7, units="in")
top10 <- Combined.markers %>% group_by(cluster) %>% top_n(n = 10, wt = avg_logFC)    
avg <- AverageExpression(Combined, features = NULL, add.ident = NULL, return.seurat = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
Combined.markers %>% group_by(cluster) %>% top_n(2000, avg_logFC) -> top

cc.features <- readLines(con = "/home/alex/lab/drugres/DropSeqFiles/regev_lab_cell_cycle_genes.txt")
s.features <- cc.features[1:43]
g2m.features <- cc.features[44:97]
CCS <- CellCycleScoring(object = Combined, s.features = s.features, g2m.features = g2m.features, set.ident = TRUE)
DoHeatmap(avg, features = c("FTH1P3", "MET", "CYR61", "NFKBIA", "RIPK2", "IFI16", "PLK2", "TNFSF10", "CEBPD", "PNRC1"), group.by = "ident", size = 3, angle = 0, combine = TRUE, draw.lines = FALSE) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7), axis.line = element_line(colour = "#ffffff")) + scale_fill_gradient2(low = '#1000ff', mid = "#ffffff", high = '#aa0101', space = "Lab", na.value = "#ffffff", midpoint = 0, guide = "colourbar", aesthetics = "fill") + coord_flip(expand = TRUE, clip = "on")
```

I tried to use the "FindAllMarkers", "group_by" and "top_n" functions to sort the gene data, and while it helped it still didn't fully sort the genes the way I wanted.

```
markers <- FindAllMarkers(Combined, features = c(genes-i-am-looking-for), only.pos = TRUE, min.pct = 0.25, thresh.use = 0.25, test.use = "biomod")
geneorder <- markers %>% group_by(cluster) %>% top_n(n = number-of-genes, wt = avg_logFC)
```

I would then replace the 'features' argument in the DoHeatMap function with the 'geneorder' object.

I know that doing a `top10 <- combined.markers` style function can get me the effect I'm looking for, but I want to do it, with specifically selected genes, rather than just the top 10 expressed per cluster.

Note: this is for v3.1 of Seurat; the latest version of Seurat at the time of asking.